# CSV Helper Convert a scientific notation into String type

Tags: csvhelper

I have a `phoneNumber` field on a csv file that has scientific notation. I need to read the actual text and store it as string.

From other documentation I was able to convert the scientific notation to a long type using `NumberStyles` but I need this as a string type.

Ex: 1.11E+09 should be "1111111111" instead of 1111111111

Comment: You should add some code here, so it's clear which language and what kind of problem appears in your "csv helper". If you are not allowed to share the code, you could write down pseudo code or an example here. Also please add more specific tags - e.g. language name , "convert", "number", "csv" - "csvhelper" should be removed as tag because not relevant for searches (IMHO). Doing this steps makes it much easier for community to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you would need to use `ConvertUsing` to get this.

```cs
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        using(var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Id,PhoneNumber");
            writer.WriteLine("1,1.11E+09");
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<TestMap>();

            var records = csv.GetRecords<Test>().ToList();
        }
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

public sealed class TestMap : ClassMap<Test>
{
    public TestMap()
    {
        AutoMap(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Map(m => m.PhoneNumber).ConvertUsing(row => decimal.Parse(row.GetField<string>("PhoneNumber"), NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint).ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way without having to use the Map file and Register it? As i am not currently using this and don't want to add that just for one property. If it's the only way, can the Map file only have the PhoneNumber map and rest of the properties would still continue to do auto Map? i am using Name attribute on the Class itself that's doing an auto map of the headers in the csv.

Comment: I just updated the answer to include`AutoMap` in the `TestMap` class.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: This looks like Excel ate your phone number data. It's gone. Go to the source.

---

This isn't a programming answer per se, but more geared towards the problem space you are in. Having worked in telecom billing, the only real solution for this problem is to go to the source of your data, inform them it is corrupted, and have them rebuild it from the source *without* using Excel, or at least to be sure that the phone number fields are treated as text.

I say that, because every time I have seen this error it is because someone somewhere in the processing chain used Excel to add or update a column of information to some raw telco switch data. This also happens with contact data where the phone numbers have been entered in a variety of formats, some of them raw numbers without other formatting (like `(cc)xxx..` or `(npa)nxx-xxxx`). Excel is allergic to raw phone numbers, because it sees them numerically. It will trim leading zeroes, and if too long, will convert to scientific notation.

Even if you succeed in converting this back to a flat integer, you will have lost much pertinent information in the phone number that is critical for routing and rating. Note that `1.11e+09` doesn't convert to `1_111_111_111` but `1_110_000_000`; in either case, neither of these are valid phone numbers in any exchange.