# Column value is converted to formula/exponent

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I am having a bit of trouble with a particular column of data when writing a CSV file. The majority of the time, the value is longer than 11 characters/digits. So it's being generated as `7.47313E+11` in the CSV, when it should really read as `747313016112`. I was initially using [this answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62538936/csv-helper-convert-a-scientific-notation-into-string-type) as a reference in an attempt to resolve my issue, but it's not working.

One thing to note is that the column in the DB (titled `Barcode`) is a varchar. However, only number values are ever saved to this column. So I guess at some point during the CSV generation process (or after the generation), Excel is recognizing it as a number, not a string.

Here's my working code thus far:

```
public static void GenerateChartsCSVFile(IEnumerable<ChartsData> chartsData)
{
    string fullPath = "C:\\chart-data.csv";

    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fullPath, true, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.WriteRecords(chartsData);

        writer.Flush();
    }

    if (File.Exists(fullPath))
        Console.WriteLine("Charts CSV file " + csvFile + " successfully created!");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Oops, something went wrong with generating the Charts CSV file.");
}
```

Data Model:

```
public class ChartsData
{
    public string CatalogueID { get; set; }
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public int DiscNo { get; set; }
    public int TrackNo { get; set; }
    public string TrackTitle { get; set; }
    public string ISRC { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }
    public string LabelID { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string TrackContributors { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Open the csv file using NotePad (instead of Excel), Are your bar codes still showing up in exponential form?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to mention that I did try that. Yes, when I opened the file in Notepad, the values for Barcode are perfect. The issue only exists in Excel.

Comment: See [Formatting a comma-delimited CSV to force Excel to interpret value as a string](https://superuser.com/questions/318420/formatting-a-comma-delimited-csv-to-force-excel-to-interpret-value-as-a-string)

Comment: @JohnWu I tried doing this, but Excel is now recognizing the extra set of double-quotes as part of the string. So now the values are looking like "747313016112" inside each Barcode cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add one set of double quotes.  CsvHelper automatically escapes quotes in the string with another set of double quotes.  The string `=""747313016112""` will end up as `=""""747313016112""""` because CsvHelper will escape each of the double quotes.  That is why your value looks like `"747313016112"` inside Excel.

```cs
chartsData.Barcode = "=\"" + chartsData.Barcode + "\"";
```

CsvHelper is following [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180)

> 7. If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
>    appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
>    another double quote.

For example:

> "aaa","b""bb","ccc"